# Cannot load html from within html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `index.html` and `navbar.html` within the same folder. The `index.html` file has the following code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#navBar").load("navbar.html");
</script>
```

The following `div` is within the `body`

```
<div id="navBar"></div>
```

The `navbar` contains this test code:

```
<p> Test File </p>
```

The github repository is here: https://github.com/roymunsonstudios/roymunsonstudios.github.io

Why is it that this simple HTML import is not working?

UPDATE:

There is an error in the console:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/vroy/Developer/Website/roymunsonstudios.github.io/navbar.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

The `index.html` file references 2 versions of JQuery. The one in the script. And another version of JQuery which is in the footer. However, for some reason the script is being run with the older version of JQuery even though I want it to use the newer version of JQuery. Should I change this?

UPDATE 2:

The error still happens with the latest version of JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the error was changing:

```
$("#navBar").load("navbar.html");
```

to:

```
$("#navBar").load("https://-to-navbar.html");
```

because the .load function only seems to work with URLs not files that are stored locally.

I also had to change the code slightly: (Credit to Rorymccrossan):

```
$(function() { <code> });
```

Answer (score 3):

As you're loading the script in the `<head>` of the document you need to place your jQuery code in a document.ready event handler. At the moment your code is being executed before the `#navBar` element exists in the DOM. Try this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#navBar").load("navbar.html");
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. Should I just not load the script in the head of the document?